# Replication Issues in Active Directory - Computer Objects showing up in multiple OUs

Tags: domain-controller, replication, active-directory, accounts

There seems to be replication issues in the domain , but there is a strange occurrence. Some computer objects are moved to a different OU ; after a day when i searched for those computer objects in ADUC;

-> When the scope is selected as entire directory , the computer object showed up in correct OU with correct time-stamp.

-> when the scope is selected as that particular domain, the computer object showed up in wrong OU with old time-stamp.

In both searches , only a single object showed up , so there is no chance of duplicate objects; does anybody know what type of replication issue is this?

Both these searches are done connected to the single DC which is at same site and same domain. Please let me know if any additional questions.

Edit: This domain controller is a GC.

Comment: Any event id 1988 events in the Directory Service event logs on the DC's?

Comment: No but i found event 1862 between all the 1226 events.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting "Entire Domain" in the "Find..." dialog causes the search to be run against the Global Catalog partition of the Active Directory. Selecting the domain causes the search to be run against the domain's partition.

It's unclear to me why you're seeing older data in the domain partition than in the Global Catalog. It *sounds* like you're looking at a domain controller (DC) that might be having trouble receiving domain partition replication. I would hypothesize that the DC you're querying isn't a Global Catalog server and, as such, you're seeing query results from a different DC that has an up-to-date copy of the Global Catalog when you perform an "Entire Directory"-scoped search.

Can you expand your question to include whether or not the DC you're querying for the domain-scoped search is a Global Catalog sever?

Comment: Updated the question , yes its a GC.